# Make [reactjs-native] a synonym of [react-native]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I came across a tag [reactjs-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs-native) with 53 questions which is an obvious duplicate of the primary tag [react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native).  I've [suggested a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/react-native/synonyms) but hopefully requesting it here is more effective.